# Spring boot - JpaRepository ничего не возвращает, при этом SQL-запрос в консоле верный, в чем проблема?

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-boot, spring-data

**Корневой контролер в котором дебажу**

```java
import com.chvalov.library.Repository.AuthorRepository;
import com.chvalov.library.Repository.BookRepository;
import lombok.extern.java.Log;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMethod;

import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;

@Controller
@Log
public class RedirectController {

    @Autowired
    private AuthorRepository authorRepository;

    @Autowired
    private BookRepository bookRepository;

    @RequestMapping(value = "", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String baseUrlRedirect(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse httpServletResponse) {

        // Пустота
        System.out.println(bookRepository.findByNameContainingIgnoreCaseOrAuthorFioContainingIgnoreCaseOrderByName("а","па"));
        System.out.println(authorRepository.findByFioContainingIgnoreCaseOrderByFio("ча"));

        // Работает
        System.out.println(authorRepository.findOne(25L));
        System.out.println(authorRepository.findAll());

        System.out.println(bookRepository.findOne(20L));
        System.out.println(bookRepository.findAll());
        return "ok";
    }
}
```

**DAO:**

*AuthDao.java*

```java
import com.chvalov.library.Entity.Author;

// описывает специфичное поведение для работы с авторами
public interface AuthorDao extends GeneralDAO<Author>{

}
```

*GeneralDao.java*

```java
import java.util.List;

// общее поведения для всех DAO объектов
public interface GeneralDAO<T>{

    List<T> getAll();
    List<T> search(String... searchString);

    T get(long id); // получение объекта по id
    T save(T obj);// save - обновляет или добавляет объект (один метод на 2 действия)
    void delete(T object);

}
```

*AuthorRepository.java*

```java
import com.chvalov.library.Entity.Author;
import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.JpaRepository;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Repository;

import java.util.List;

@Repository // специальный Spring bean, который помечает интерфейс как Repository
public interface AuthorRepository extends JpaRepository<Author, Long> {// JpaRepository - содержит CRUD функционал + постраничность

    // на основании имени метода будет построен Hibernate запрос
    List<Author> findByFioContainingIgnoreCaseOrderByFio(String fio);
}
```

При выполнении:

```java
authorRepository.findByFioContainingIgnoreCaseOrderByFio("ча");
```

Возвращает пустые данные, сам SQL запрос в консоле верный, записи в БД есть и нормально выбириются тем-же запросом в Navicat & phpMyAdmin

[image: JpaRepository SpringBoot return empty]

Данный код возвращает нужные данные:

```java
authorRepository.findOne(25L);
authorRepository.findAll();
```

[image: Repository Spring-Boot return null]

**В чем проблема, почему возвращает пустые данные ?**

**UPD:** Лог с MySQL:

```sql
2018-01-20T04:02:37.615823Z   754 Query /* select generatedAlias0 from Author as generatedAlias0 where upper(generatedAlias0.fio) like upper(:param0) order by generatedAlias0.fio asc */ select author0_.id as id1_0_, author0_.birthday as birthday2_0_, author0_.fio as fio3_0_ from library.author author0_ where upper(author0_.fio) like upper('%??%') order by author0_.fio asc
2018-01-20T04:02:37.616909Z   754 Query set session transaction read only
2018-01-20T04:02:37.617245Z   754 Query SET autocommit=0
2018-01-20T04:02:37.618412Z   754 Query select author0_.id as id1_0_0_, author0_.birthday as birthday2_0_0_, author0_.fio as fio3_0_0_ from library.author author0_ where author0_.id=25
2018-01-20T04:02:37.621222Z   754 Query commit
2018-01-20T04:02:37.635841Z   754 Query SET autocommit=1
2018-01-20T04:02:37.638517Z   754 Query select @@session.tx_read_only
2018-01-20T04:02:37.639451Z   754 Query set session transaction read write
2018-01-20T04:02:37.641171Z   754 Query /* select generatedAlias0 from Author as generatedAlias0 where upper(generatedAlias0.fio) like upper(:param0) order by generatedAlias0.fio asc */ select author0_.id as id1_0_, author0_.birthday as birthday2_0_, author0_.fio as fio3_0_ from library.author author0_ where upper(author0_.fio) like upper('%??%') order by author0_.fio asc
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В файле *application.properties* 
к строке:

`spring.datasource.url=jdbc:mysql://<IP>:<PORT>/<DB_NAME>`
Добавить

`?useUnicode=yes&characterEncoding=UTF-8&characterSetResults=UTF-8`